# Get element by id from an activerecord hash with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get my hash using this :

```
@hotels = Hotel.all
```

it returns : 
    [Hotel1, Hotel2...]

How can i extract from this hash the Hotel id=10 for example?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Hotel.all returns an array, not a hash. Why not Hotel.find(10)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find a single element from the Array:

```
@hotels.find { |h| h.id == 10 }
#=> Hotel10
```

You might be better off doing Hotel.find(10) instead, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
@hotels.select{|h| h.id==10}
#=>[Hotel10]
```

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. @hotels.select returns an Array, so the correct result value would be `[Hotel10]`

Answer (score 0):

Try [Array#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-select)

```
a.select {|hotel| hotel.id == 10}
```

Comment: because I don't know this method :)